# how to fetch the records in mongodb with php

Tags: hyperlink, sample

I have an experience in php & mysql.In MYSQL  Using the query  " **SELECT * from Tablename**"   fetch e all the records from the table . Also using the limit and group by  etc can control the records display. Based on condition and the user need, use these parametres thru PHP  pass to MYSQL can get the records .In Mongodb  structure is Complex BIJSON Structre .IN this in My Application Structre is multi level associative array is stored in date folders(Like 2020-07, 2020-08,2020-09 etc) . In this how to fetch the records between date range( startdate,endate) ?

I tried the main folder object array (data) to find the records . After that data object array inside the dates folder list available .the date folder names are not in common. Each specifically mentioned ((Like 2020-07, 2020-08,2020-09 etc) listed .Inside date folder Also Listing folders Available(like MedianListPrice,MonthOfSupply etc). So its hard to find out based on date range between with some condition ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I think you're looking for this:

mongo [$lte](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/)
mongo [$gte](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/)

in mongodb we use $gte and $lte, greater or equal operator and lesser or equal operator, you can use them separately or together within an object, the link has very simple examples for you to follow

Comment: Hi I tried that but here the issue is the collection object don't have common field name like date or created date here the field name is( 2021-03 or 2021-04 ' like that etc)